# Subspace algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

$C=\{f:f(x_{0})=3\} $ is a subset of vector space $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) $ 
Find if $C$ is also subspace of $F$.

My solution:

$g, h \subset C$

$(g+h)(x_{0}) = g(x_{0}) + h(x_{0}) = 6 \neq 3 $ It's not subspace.

How to understand  $C=\{f:f(x_{0})=3\} $ ?

Is it enough to say that the null vector $f=0$ doesn't belong to $ C$ and because of that $C$ is not a subspace?

Comment: Your solution is correct. It is enough to say that the neutral element doesn't belong to $C$. Clearly $C$ is not a vector space.

Comment: Your first solution is fine. It's also true that the null vector doesn't belong to $C$, and that's perhaps a slightly simpler proof that $C$ is not a subspace.

Comment: It's not at all clear that $C$ is not a vector space. What's true is that $C$ is not a subspace (i.e., that with the *inherited operations* it's not a vector space).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is enough to observe that the zero function does not belong to $C$. So $C$ cannot be a subspace! Further, you had shown also that the sum of two function $f,g\in C$ does not belong to $C$. 
So all kind of pathologies happen and thus $C$ is not a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

First, your answers are both correct proofs that $C$ is not a subspace of $V = F(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$.

I'd like to note that $C$ *does* admit a vector-space structure, though, because the distinction between "vector space" and "vector subspace" is often lost, as @Mathematicans 42's comment shows.

Let
$$
u(x) = 3
$$
for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Now for $f, g \in C$, define
$$
f \oplus g
$$
by
$$
f \oplus g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R : x \mapsto f(x) + g(x) - 3. 
$$
And for $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $f \in V$, define
$$
\alpha \odot f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R : x \mapsto \alpha (f(x) - 3) + 3.
$$

Under the operations $\oplus$ and $\odot$, the set $C$ *does* form a vector space, with $u$ as the identity for $\oplus$. I'll leave to verification of the axioms to the reader, but note that the map
$$
f \mapsto f - u
$$
is an isomorphism from $C$ (with this vector space structure) to the subspace $C' \subset V$ consisting of all functions with $f(x_0) = 0$.